# Ruby on rails edit article comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Objective is to edit an article comment.

However I can only figure out how to show a new comment field using `<%= render 'form', comment: @comment %>` or the comment text that is already there using `<%= render 'comment', comment: @comment %>` within edit.html.erb

Also tried changing `<%= form_with model: [@article, @article.comments.build] do |form| %>` to `<%= form_with model: @article.comment do |form| %>` but results in NoMethodError in Comments#edit

**views/comments/edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Edit comment</h1>
<%= render 'comment', comment: @comment %>
```

**comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model: [@article, @article.comments.build] do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :status %>
    <%= form.select :status, ['public', 'private', 'archived'], selected: 'public' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**comments/_comment.html.erb**

```
<p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<%= link_to "Edit comment", edit_article_comment_path(comment.article, comment) %>
<p>
  <%= link_to "Destroy comment", [comment.article, comment], data: {
    turbo_method: :delete,
    turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?"
  } %>
</p>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: [:index, :show]

  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comments = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article), status: :see_other
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    # redirect_to article_path(@comment)

    if @comment.update(comment_params)
      redirect_to @comment
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
  end
end
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to root_path, status: :see_other
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :status)
  end

end
```

**views/articles/show.html.erb**

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>

<p><%= @article.body %></p>

<ul>
  <li> <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %></li>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Destroy", article_path(@article),
                data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
  </li>
</ul>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @article.comments %>

<h2>Add a comment</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

new **comment/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model: @comment do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :status %>
    <%= form.select :status, ['public', 'private', 'archived'], selected: 'public' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

new **articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @article.comments.new
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to root_path, status: :see_other
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :status)
  end

end
```

With the inclusion of `@comment = @article.comments.new` results in `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Articles#show` `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :article_id=>"11", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]`  on 'show.html.erb' for an article. Without that and with the changes to form_with I am not able to create a comment - no errors are shown.

Comment: `<%= render 'form', comment: @comment %>`  - that comment is not used, you can do `<%= render 'form' %>` and it'll work exactly the same. Which is to say, use this parameter in the partial.

Comment: Try this: `<%= form_with model: [@article, comment]`

Comment: Thanks, i tried that but receive the error `undefined local variable or method comment for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000001ae00>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post beacuse I had the same problem, and thanks to @Chiperific's response I found a solution for this. I have a similar situation, with object Shopping that has many Items objects.

These are my new and edit views for Items

```
<h2>Aggiungi articoli</h2>
<div id="divform">
 <%= render 'items/form' %>
</div>

<h2>Modifica Articolo</h2>
<div id="divform">
 <%= render 'items/form' %>
</div>
```

This is my _form.html.erb for Items

```
<%= form_with model: [ @shopping, @item ], remote: true do |form| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :quantity %><br>
    <%= form.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :unit_price %><br>
    <%= form.number_field :unit_price, step: :any, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

These are my actions in the Items_controller

```
def new
  @shopping = Shopping.find(params[:shopping_id])
  @item = @shopping.items.new
end

def create
  @shopping = Shopping.find(params[:shopping_id])
  @item = @shopping.items.create(item_params)
  @item.update(item_params)
  redirect_to edit_shopping_path(@shopping)
end

def edit
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @shopping = Shopping.find(@item.shopping_id)
end

def update
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @shopping = Shopping.find(params[:shopping_id])
  if @item.update(item_params)
    redirect_to edit_shopping_path(@shopping)
  else
    render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

With this link I click to edit an Item object:

```
<%= link_to "Modifica", edit_shopping_item_path(item.shopping_id, item), class: 'btn btn-success btn-xs' %>
```

And in my form I can create an Item object for the New action, and if I click on the link to edit an Item, I see the form fields populated with the item properties' values, and if I submit the form, the Item object is updated.
Thanks @Chiperific for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

As in nearly all things computers, your form is actually doing exactly what you're telling it to do:

`<%= form_with model: [@article, @article.comments.build] do |form| %>`

1. `build` a new instance of an `@articles.comments` object
2. Display a form of that new `comment`'s attributes (which at the moment are mostly nil because it's brand new)

Your existing code probably already works great for ***creating*** a ***new*** comment.

If you're trying to ***edit*** an ***existing*** comment, I think this may help you see that you're asking the form to do the wrong thing.

A few notes:

- `@article.comment` isn't a thing (in this case) since it's pretty clear that an Article `has_many` Comments.

(Hence Rails says `NoMethodError`. it's telling you an instance of `Article` doesn't have a method called `comment`.)

- `@article.comments` is a collection of all comments related to that `@article`

It will always be a collection (an array), even if there's only one or even none. If you wanted the body of the first comment you'd have to say `@articles.comments.first.body`; if you tried to call `@articles.comments.body` you'd get another `NoMethodError`.

- `@article.comments.build` "builds" (or "instantiates into memory without saving") a ***new*** comment, by default all it's attributes are nil and this is what you're seeing in the form currently.

Here's a bunch of other ways of instantiating a new comment:

- `Comment.new` <- no association to an `Article`
- `Comment.new(article_id: @article.id)` <- associated to `@article`
- `Comment.new(article: @article)` <- same, because Rails is smart
- `@article.comments.new` <- associated to `@article`

You are setting `@comment` in the controller (`@comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])`), so just use that:

```
<%= form_with model: @comment do |form| %>
  <!--- all the same code you already have -->
<% end %>
```

**BUT WAIT**, if you just change the `form_with` code in `comments/_form.html.erb`, your form will work for ***editing*** but will no longer work for ***creating***.

You didn't include a `new` action in your `CommentsController`, I'm assuming that's because the "new comments" form is being displayed via one of your `ArticlesController` actions, probably `#show`, that's pretty common.

#### So, what's the fix?

Since you're using a partial, you're trying to re-use the `_form.html.erb` code for multiple purposes, which is smart and will work **if** the `@comment` variable can change to adapt to the need.

When you want to edit an existing comment, `@comment` must be set to the existing comment you actually want to edit. You're in luck, that's already the case.

When you want to create a new comment, `@comment` must be a new comment already associated with the correct `@article`. You can do so like this: `@comment = @article.comments.new` (or `.build` if you really like that better)

Where do you add this new variable? In whatever `ArticlesController` action you're using to display the "new comments" form (e.g. the place you're referencing the `comments/new.html.erb` file):

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @article.comments.new
  end
end
```

Now when `comments/_form.html.erb` is rendered:

- In `/articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit` then `@comment` will be set to an existing Comment record
- In `/articles/:id` then `@comment` will be set to a new Comment record that is associated with `@article`

Hope this rambling answer helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have gained useful info from this. However, still no luck. ArticleController only contains `def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end`.  Amending _form file to @comment results in 'NoMethodError in Comments#Edit' and 'undefined method `comment_path'. Having @comments instead shows blank text areas alike the original problem. If it helps, i configured my Article and Comment using this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Comment: Please update your question to include the contents of `ArticlesController`, any changes you made to partials and controllers based on my answer and the full error messages you're now getting.

Comment: Please also post whatever view is calling `controllers/_form.html.erb` for creating new comments.